# C# Server for MMORPG, thread-safety with async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety

If I have 1 thread for my MMORPG server running a async socket and async packet handler, and in that 1 thread I have a static World that contains all entities in the game.

Would there be any threading issues if say, the async packet handler recieves an Attack message, resulting in a search of the entities in the world to figure out the target.

At the same time the static World Proc method is increasing the size of the Dictionary containing the monster entities adding extra monsters that spawned.

If this is all on the same thread, will the server explode?

Comment: What do you mean explode?

Comment: can you be more specific about how you are handling the async network IO on a single thread? but yes: if you have two threads accessing a dictionary - one of them changing it: then things can get very sour. You can have as many readers as you like, as long as nobody is writing. Incidentally, `Hashtable` supports multiple readers **plus** at most one writer. Which can be handy.

Comment: :P. meaning it will throw a exception "Collection size changed or something else"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx  read data from socket passing socket + data to callback handler which calls functions by passing as delegate

Comment: a delegate is on the same thread thought, I think?  Why do you say 2 threads?

Comment: @VansS a delegate doesn't have a specific thread: it is a thing-to-do; the point is that the callback happens on the IO completion's thread - some arbitrary worker thread.

Comment: Maybe uses reg sockets would be better then, with each connected client having an instance of the packet handler. 

I am just not sure how to sync the monsters with the clients.

Placing a lock on the main dictionary I think would be a problem if there are 500+ concurrent clients correct?

Comment: You could take a look at the ConcurrentDictionary class if you want to access objects in a thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the server explode?

Yes, you can run into problems ("explode") because the async stuff is running on a different thread (even though you didn't create that thread explicitly) and it might access a shared object (world) at the same time as your main thread. Many datastructures (including the Dictionary) are not designed for this scenario and might crash or return the wrong answer.

The typical approach is to use locks to protect your shared objects: take the lock before modifying it, do whatever modification, and then release the lock. This way, only one thread at a time accesses the world (and its dictionary) and so everything remains consistent. Explosion averted.

Another way would be to switch to a more synchronous form of networking, perhaps for example avoiding completion handlers and instead waiting to hear from each of the players, and then acting on the inputs. This can be done very simply, but the simple way has drawbacks: any one slow player can slow the whole thing down. So sadly you're probably going to have to deal with some complexity, one way or another.

Comment: I am wondering if locking the main dict will incur performance issues tho, or if it would not be noticeable

Comment: Yes, locks can have a performance impact. Being slow but correct is often better than fast but exploded, though. That said, you can minimize the impact by doing most of the computations beforehand and holding the lock for only as long as you have to.

Answer (score 0):

If I give answer in one line. Server will explode. As network activity and game logic is in same thread. And as you have mentioned you will be needing high network usage.

I seriously like that if you have a look to [F#](http://www.tryfsharp.org/). It has all the things that you needed. As far as I got it from question. And few things are like collection change, and async is by default in language. Even [Nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) it is also worth trying. But again it all depends on requirement. Though I try to explain few keywords that may help you to take decision.

Non-blocking : It means thread will not be block on events. It will not wait for function to wait for another function to execute. But that doesn't mean you can't block it. In any case it is a single thread.

Async: It is some what like that. But in C# 5 async comes with keyword so you don't have to do threading part of programming.

Parallel Processing: In game development parallel processing is important. Now, that you can do with multiple thread or just use [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

In the case of UI based (where there are many objects) game I highly recommended that you separate processing thread and UI thread to improve user experience. Else FPS will go down while you are processing data.

Let me know if any further information needed.

Server will not go down if you take little care of it.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @Corey thanks for pointing out. I have added few more details for clarification. Please let me know if any more detail required.

Answer (score 0):

If on the same thread, then no.  If you are doing all the work mentioned on a single thread, then there's no issue.  However, as stated, if you are accessing a "shared" object instance across threads, then yes, there will be an issue, and locking will be required (using a "lock(){...}" block).

As your user base increases, you will have to keep an eye on the number of threads generated, or event messages if using a non-blocking event model for incoming requests.

On a different, yet related note, keep an eye on this C# based MMO server (with scripting support): https://dreamspace.codeplex.com/ - it may become a big help to MMO game creators very soon (will support Construct 2 by default).